# set referenced entity programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I have a view that displays a content type "offers" for a specific "task" (content type), the "task" content type has an entity reference field that reference an "offer". The view shows the title of the "offers" and in front of each title a button "Select this offer for your task"

I want that when I click the button "Select this offer for your task" set the value of the entity reference field I have in the "task" node, for reference the offer I have selected from the view

Is this possible?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are already using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views), consider using the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) with [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module.  This kind of setup could be done quite easily and even stored in a [Feature](https://drupal.org/project/features) so that the changes could be maintained in a git repository.

Comment: Nice did not know the Rules Link module nice thank you!